# Cambiar un icono usando únicamente CSS

Tags: css, dropdown

Tengo un sidebar en un proyecto con `React` y deseo que, al abrir un item de menu tipo `Dropdown`, la flecha cambie de posicion según el estado del dropdown. (cerrado hacia la derecha, abierto hacia abajo).

Lo implementé con useState y funciona sin problemas, dependiendo del `state`actual del `dropdown`coloco un icono u otro.

Ahora, mi gran duda es:

> Se puede simular este comportamiento usando únicamente CSS? (prefiero hacerlo asi para aprender por un lado, y principalmente porque si tengo un sidebar con 10 dropdowns o mas, voy a tener muchos estados y no es la idea).

Nota: Lo mas parecido que encontre fue `selector:focus`, pero no me permitia retirar el focus al volver a clickear en el item del menú. Solo se retiraba si clickeo fuera, por lo que no me simula el comportamiento exactamente igual que con el uso del hook useState.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

/* Fixed sidenav, full height */
.sidenav {
  height: 60%;
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

/* Style the sidenav links and the dropdown button */
.sidenav a, .dropdown-btn {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

/* Dropdown container (hidden by default). Optional: add a lighter background color and some left padding to change the design of the dropdown content */
.dropdown-container {
  display: none;
  background-color: #262626;
  padding-left: 8px;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="sidenav">
  <button class="dropdown-btn">Dropdown 
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>


<script>
/* Loop through all dropdown buttons to toggle between hiding and showing its dropdown content - This allows the user to have multiple dropdowns without any conflict */
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
  dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.classList.toggle("active");
  var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
  if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
  dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
  } else {
  dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
  }
  });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

> NOTA: El comportamiento que deseo imitar es el que pueden ver en los dropdown-items del sidebar de este sitio:

https://demos.creative-tim.com/argon-dashboard-pro-react/?_ga=2.107827714.1692546048.1606391252-195183447.1606391252#/admin/react-bs-table

Comment: Quizás sea posible con clases adicionales, de modo que cada clase adicional determine una subfamilia de dropdowns que alterna un par de iconos en los estados. Eso haría que los comportamientos se manejen con las clases usuales y las extra definen aspectos específicos.

Comment: No te entiendo muy bien. Lo mas parecido que pude hacer fue con scss y la pseudo-class :focus. Le digo que al hacer focus en el dropdown reemplace la visibilidad de las flechas, de esa manera anda de lujo. El tema es que Focus no funciona como un elemento Check por ejemplo. Yo para remover un :focus tengo que clickear en cualquier otro lado. La idea es que para remover el :focus vuelva a hacer click el mismo boton

Comment: Los dropdowns tienen un juego de clases para ul, li, a, etc. Y, los plugins las emplean para controlar su comportamiento. Si les agregas una clase adicional ej: extra1, puedes agregar reglas para **.dropdown-menu .extra1 pseudoclase|.clase_de_estado** de modo que tenga los iconos que quieras para las pseudoclases. Solo necesitas poner tus reglas al final o en una hoja css que cargue de última. Los selectores se ajustan un poco para precisar lo que se desee.

Comment: Yo logro seleccionar los elementos correctamente y darle propiedades de acuerdo a la pseudoclase. El tema es que probe varias maneras y ninguna simula 100% lo que hace javascript. 1) :focus -> Hace todo exactamente como yo lo quiero, excepto cuando quiero cerrar el dropdown. Solo sucede si le hago click fuera del mismo, lo ideal sería poder remover el focus clickeando nuevamente, pero bueno, focus no funciona asi, jeje. 2) Lo mejor que encontre fue esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630229/can-i-have-an-onclick-effect-in-css (Te explico lo que pasa en el proximo comentario)

Comment: @quevedo Esta ultima opcion me parecio genial, simular el comportamiento con un checked display none. El tema es que cuando, en lugar de poner cualquier contenido dentro de la etiqueta Label, pongo lo que necesito (Un elemento Link de ract-router-dom) no funciona. Probe reemplazar dicho Link por elementos comunes como a, p, button, div, etc. Dandole propiedades como role='button', pero siempre que vuelvo dinamico el contenido del label, deja de funcionar y no checkea/uncheckea el checkbox

Comment: @quevedo por ultimo probé :target pero pasa lo mismo que focus, no funciona al clickear nuevamente el elemento. Yo se que si aplico JavaScript lo saco enseguida, lo mismo con hooks de react. Pero estoy seguro que se puede simular con CSS y no sé como

Comment: Voy a hacer unas pruebas. De hecho **siempre uso js + css** de modo que no tengo experiencia usando sólo css. Voy a tratar de combinar alternativas y si logro algo te aviso.